# Restore file after mistakenly solving a conflict in TFS check-in

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is it possible by any chance to recover a file that has been overwritten when solving conflicts during TFS check-in?

Does Visual Studio stores a backup of this file anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can roll back the check-in to restore the previous version.

Comment: I need the "intermediate" version (after the check-out) and before the check-in conflict.

Comment: It sounds like your talking about a version of the file that only ever existed locally.  If true then your basically screwed, it's gone.